# Can I use an extension method in Entity Framework SubQuery?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to consolidate logic for accessing different tables using Entity Framework. I created an extension method for pulling all registrations from my registration entity where the person is attending:

```
public static IEnumerable<Registration> Attending(this IEnumerable<Registration> registrations)
{
    return registrations.Where(r => r.Status == RegistrationStatus.Paid || r.Status == RegistrationStatus.Assigned || r.Status == RegistrationStatus.Completed);
}
```

This works great for queries like this:

```
var attendees = db.Registrations.Attending().ToList();
```

But it doesn't work when used in a subquery:

```
ProductTotals = db.Products.Where(p => p.EventID == ev.Id).Select(p => new ProductSummaryViewModel
{
    ProductID = p.ProductID,
    ProductName = p.Name,
    Registrations = p.Registrations.Attending().Count(),
}).ToList();
```

I get the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Registration]
>   Attending(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Registration])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there any way re-use that code in a subquery?

Comment: You can use `AsEnumerable()` before the `Select` to perform the operation in memory. Though you lose the advantages of performing it at the database level.

Comment: That method should be accepting and returning an `IQueryable` not an `IEnumerable` if you're using it on EF queries, otherwise the query isn't being performed on the database.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, I noticed the same thing and changed that to use IQueryable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main thing you're trying to achieve is reusing the predicate that defines the meaning of `Attending`. You can do that by storing the expression in a readonly variable that is available to whoever needs it in your application, for example in a static class `ExpressionConstants`.

```
public static readonly Expression<Func<Registration, bool>> IsAttending = 
    r => r.Status == RegistrationStatus.Paid
      || r.Status == RegistrationStatus.Assigned
      || r.Status == RegistrationStatus.Completed;
```

Then you can do

```
var attendees = db.Registrations.Where(ExpressionConstants.IsAttending).ToList();
```

And used in the subquery:

```
ProductTotals = db.Products.Where(p => p.EventID == ev.Id).Select(p => new ProductSummaryViewModel
{
    ProductID = p.ProductID,
    ProductName = p.Name,
    Registrations = p.Registrations.AsQueryable() // AsQueryable()
                     .Where(ExpressionConstants.IsAttending).Count(),
})
```

The `AsQueryable()` is necessary because `p.Registrations` probably is an `ICollection`.