# How to create an extension method that Entity Framework can translate to an SQL query?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, extension-methods

I am creating a simple search function on a website. The search function should just look for a string in the different properties of a list of objects (IQueryable).

The objects come from an Oracle Database table using Entity Framework.

`IQueryable<SupplierAddress> data = _dbContext.SupplierAddresses;`

Next we filter this IQueryable with the searchString that was given in by the user:

```
    data = data.Where(d =>                                
    d.Supplier.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm.Trim()) || 
    d.Supplier.NameCleaned.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm.Trim()) || 
    d.Supplier.NameShort.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm.Trim()) ||   
    d.Supplier.NameShortCleaned.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm.Trim()) ||
    d.Town.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm.Trim()) ||   
    d.Country.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm.Trim());
```

Now, as you can see, we use .Trim() to prevent errors (the one mentioned in this question: [ORA-01425: escape character must be character string of length 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129119/ora-01425-escape-character-must-be-character-string-of-length-1)). Because of this error, we also can't trim the searchString before doing the filtering.

I'm trying to create an extension method that does both the .Trim() of the searchString as well as the .Contains. This extension method should be interpretable by Entity Framework and should be able to be translated to a correct SQL query by EF.

This is my current Extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsTrim(this string source, string toCheck)
    {
        return source.Contains(toCheck.Trim());
    }
}
```

But when using it like this, it can't be succesfully translated to an SQL Query.

```
    data = data.Where(d =>                                
    d.Supplier.Name.ToUpper().ContainsTrim(searchTerm) || 
    d.Supplier.NameCleaned.ToUpper().ContainsTrim(searchTerm) || 
    d.Supplier.NameShort.ToUpper().ContainsTrim(searchTerm) ||   
    d.Supplier.NameShortCleaned.ToUpper().ContainsTrim(searchTerm) ||
    d.Town.ToUpper().ContainsTrim(searchTerm) ||   
    d.Country.Name.ToUpper().ContainsTrim(searchTerm));
```

We get the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the 
method 'Boolean ContainsTrim(System.String, System.String)' method, and 
this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
```

Is it possible to make an Extension method that does both the trimming and the contain that can also be interpreted by EF?

I've also seen things like storing expressions in variables (such as here: [Can I use an extension method in Entity Framework SubQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624307/can-i-use-an-extension-method-in-entity-framework-subquery)) which may also solve my problem, but the expression needs to be able to receive a parameter (the searchString).

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: *Don't* use Trim or ToUpper at all. That just covers up the problem and introduces a huge performance hit - full table scans instead of inex seeks. Clean up the data while loading instead.

Comment: Database comparison rules are case-*insensitive* in most cases, so `ToUpper()` isn't needed unless someone used a case-*sensitive* collation.  `.Trim()` is bad because applying any kind of function on a column prevents the server from using any indexes, which means the server will have to scan the entire table to find matching rows. Scanning an entire table leads to increased blocking too. Imagine scanning 100K or even 10K rows to find a match when an index could return the matching rows instantly.

Comment: Finally, `.Contains()` is equivalent to `LIKE '%something%'`, another thing that can't use indexes, unless full-text search indexes are used

Comment: As for *the specific question*, EF translates the expression trees generated by a LINQ query into SQL. It doesn't execute any methods. *This specific method though* doesn't do anything more that call `.Contains()`. The search term should be trimmed *before* the query and reused. That takes away the need for `ContainsTrim` altogether

Comment: A *far* better option though would be to use [Oracle Text](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#BABGAIHJ) to index all the rows and query them using eg `CONTAINS`